# Starting on learning SWT in eclipse, why won't this label change location

Tags: eclipse, swt, label

Im doing a tutorial and i added a few labels myself to test it out and throw a few things around to get a better grip on it, and labellast.setLocation seems to just do nothing to labellast, the location of the label wont change...

Here is my source:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(250, 350);

    Label label1 = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    label1.setText("Hello World!");
    label1.setSize(100, 20);
    label1.setLocation(30, 30);

    Text text1 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text1.setText("Type Here");
    text1.setTextLimit(50);
    text1.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 20);
    text1.setLocation(30, 60);

    Label hello = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    hello.setText("type what the top line says.");
    hello.setSize(190, 20);
    hello.setLocation(30, 90);

    Label sep1 = new Label(shell, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL
            | SWT.SHADOW_IN);
    sep1.setBounds(30, 60, 100, 120);
    Label label2 = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label2.setText("World Hello");
    label2.setSize(100, 20);
    label2.setLocation(30, 150);

    Label sep2 = new Label(shell, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    sep2.setBounds(30, 120, 100, 20);

    Label label3 = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label3.setSize(100, 20);
    label3.setLocation(30, 210);
    label3.setBackground(new Color(display, 200, 111, 50));
    label3.setText("World World.");

    Text text2 = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
    text2.setEchoChar('*');
    text2.setBounds(10, 50, 200, 20);
    text2.setText("Password");
    text2.setLocation(30, 250);
    text2.setEditable(false);

    Label labellast = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    labellast.setLocation(30, 300);
    labellast.setText("You cant edit that^^^");
    labellast.setBounds(10, 50, 200, 20);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();

    }
    display.dispose();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `setBounds` sets both the position and size.

```
setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Get rid of the call to `setLocation` and just use `setBounds`:

```
labellast.setText("You cant edit that^^^");
labellast.setBounds(30, 300, 200, 20);
```

In your code you are calling `setLocation` first, then later overriding the position when you call `setBounds` which makes it look like you can't change the location.

Comment: thanks! this tutorial is a bit misleading in that aspect as it has been telling me to have a set location and bounds for each one... I was confused as to what all four parameters for setBounds did in the first place.